# PHP / JQuery - Load data only if clicked in an user on the list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, load

hey well i am making a messaging system in a page which contains online users now i want to load old messages only when i click on an user not on page load so the connection doesn't get slower.Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, that is possible. What is your question?

Comment: Where is your code ? What have you tried so far ? What results do you get when you run your code? Please add all relevant info.

Comment: I tried the iframe src but it loads when page loads not when i click on one of the users

Comment: Please show your code @ŠîdøüLãCørnïché

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that with an Ajax request.

I'll give you a fast example.

You need two files:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Main Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li class="users" id="1">First User</li>
        <li class="users" id="2">Second User</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="result"></div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $("li").click(function(event) {
                var user_id = event.target.id;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "request_data.php",
                    data: "id=" + user_id,
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                      $("#result").html(msg);
                    },
                    error: function()
                    {
                      alert("Error: ajax call failed.");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

request_data.php

```
<?php
// Get user id submitted information
$user_id = $_POST["id"];
// here you could make your query to the db and stamp the result
echo "The id of the user is: ".$user_id;
?>
```

Hoping to be helpful. :)

Comment: Thanks that's what i was looking for

Comment: Happy to help. If the answer is correct then click to accept it.